# Why "No compiler" on my Windows 7 when typing mex -setup in r2010a?

Tags: matlab

I am using Windows 7 64 bits. I need to do the mex -largeArrayDims *.c but it tells me that there is no compiler. I am trying to do this in R2010a.

I tried mex -setup but still it says there is no compiler. How can I fix this? Can you please help me? I downloaded Mingw-w64 from the project's SourceForge page (this was before the project moved to http://mingw-w64.org/) but I don't know how to use it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mingw is not supported by Matlab. You must use a compiler supported by them. I believe Visual Studio should be supported and I see no reason why it wouldn't work with the Express Editions, which are free.

*EDIT*
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2010a/win64.html#simulink

You need a patch for Matlab 2010a to use Visual Studio 2010. Under "Notes for the Windows (64-bit) Platform", Read item two, it should explain how to get VC++ 2010 recognized by Matlab. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have Visual Studio. Now what should I do to make this work? I really don't know what I am doing. I will start doing something as soon as I have something in my hand that can be executed.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Professional it says

Comment: after I mex it once, don't I need to do it with Matlab too or is it just one time only?

Comment: Check my edited answer up above, there is a patch you need to download to make it work with VC++ 2010.