# How can I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 to create MEX files with MATLAB 7.10 (R2010a)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, libsvm, mex

following the questions :
[How to set up LIBSVM Matlab interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954007/how-to-set-up-libsvm-matlab-interface)
[Why “No compiler” on my Windows 7 when typing mex -setup in r2010a?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861891/why-no-compiler-on-my-windows-7-when-typing-mex-setup-in-r2010a)
I encountered the link:
[How can I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 to create MEX files with MATLAB 7.10 (R2010a)?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93013)
It is said in the page that the patch will support these combinations:

```
• Visual C++ 2010 Professional and 64-bit MATLAB 7.10 (R2010a)

• Visual C++ 2010 Professional and 32-bit MATLAB 7.10 (R2010a)

• Visual C++ 2010 Express (Windows SDK 7.1 also required) and 64-bit MATLAB 7.10 (R2010a)

• Visual C++ 2010 Express and 32-bit MATLAB 7.10 (R2010a)
```

But I have `Visual C++ 2010 Ultimate` installed on my notebook. How can I understand whether the patch will support this combination or not?

```
• Visual C++ 2010 Ultimate and 64-bit MATLAB 7.10 (R2010a)
```

Comment: yes the patch should work with the Ultimate version of VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure.

Firstly, you should add the **include** folder, **libs** folder into the VS include & libs.

Secondly, you implement your mex file via C++, you should include the mex.h file into your source code first, and then the mexFunction must supplied according to the rule of the mex. As follows:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

Thirdly, you should add the libs into the **Additional Dependencies**, for example, libmx.lib，libmat.lib，libmex.lib etc..

PS: When you tried to implement a matlab mex project, you should create a dll project using VS, in fact, the mex file(mexw32 & mexw64) is a special dll file. So the file generated by VS is a dll file, if you want the VS generate a mex file, you can change the file name via modify the config item of VS project or just rename the file after them generated.

Here, I just show you some code:

```
#include "Rectification.h"
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, 
             const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
    if (nrhs != 4)
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt("You need input just 4 parameters!");
    }

    int m1 = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    int n1 = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

    int m2 = mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    int n2 = mxGetN(prhs[1]);

    int m3 = mxGetM(prhs[2]);
    int n3 = mxGetN(prhs[2]);

    int m4 = mxGetM(prhs[3]);
    int n4 = mxGetN(prhs[3]);

    double* temp1 = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    double* temp2 = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    double* temp3 = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    double* temp4 = mxGetPr(prhs[3]);

    CMatrix size(m1, n1, temp1);
    CMatrix inliers1(m2, n2, temp2);
    CMatrix inliers2(m3, n3, temp3);
    CMatrix fMatrix(m4, n4, temp4);

    CMatrix h1, h2;

    CalH(size, inliers1, inliers2, fMatrix, h1, h2);

    int om1 = h1.GetmRows();
    int on1 = h1.GetmCols();
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(om1, on1, mxREAL);
    double* outMat1 = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < om1*on1; i++)
    {
        *(outMat1 + i) = *(h1.GetmData() + i);
    }

    int om2 = h2.GetmRows();
    int on2 = h2.GetmCols();
    plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(om2, on2, mxREAL);
    double* outMat2 = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < om2*on2; i++)
    {
        *(outMat2 + i) = *(h2.GetmData() + i);
    }
}
```

If you need, I can share my project with you.

Comment: well @Berlin I understood that you say to build mex file in VS and then add it to the matlab toolbox folder on my notebook. This is right if I have all .lib, .h and .dll files but I don't have them. If i have the source code it will be easy to build .dlls and .libs using VS. But the problem is it is a university homework assighnment and I am permitted to just use the matlab interface of libsvm. And make the mex using matlab. My question was exactly `Will the patch obtained by mathworks usable with ultimate edition of VS2010 or I am forced to use a later version of matlab?`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I had done this like you said. The header file of the mex.h and the libs are in the $matlab dir\extern\include, $matlab dir\extern\include\win32 and $matlab dir\extern\lib\win32\microsoft.

Comment: @Berlin: while this should work the way you described, it is easier to use the [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) command from inside MATLAB; it will build your MEX-functions without the need to manually create VS projects and adjusting the paths and libraries. All you need is to run `mex -setup` at least once to properly select a supported compiler.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. There are two method to generate a mex file. What I said before is one of them. 

Yes, we can also generate the mex file via matlab command, firstly you should setup the compiler, if you have installed the VS 10 on your PC, when you run `mex -setup`, there is a vc 11 compiler item should can be selected, and secondly, use `mex source.c` to build the mex.

Comment: @Belin: yes, thats correct. Of course it depends on your version of MATLAB as to what VS compilers are supported (older MATLAB versions didn't know about VS2013 for example! Also MathWorks tend to remove support for older compilers as they release new versions). btw the process of manually compiling MEX-files is described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/custom-building-mex-files.html), which should always work no matter what version you have..